# Why aren't the values of a select element being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Although assigning values to select elements seems trivial, I fail to understand why the code below sets the values to null rather  than the correct ones for "form-type" and "genre". All other fields are set correctly.

Note that the options are being added dynamically from a database call.

View [test-site.](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/manage-uploads)

If you are inclined to downvote this question, please provide a reason so I can learn from my mistakes.

The getSuccess function is a callback from an ajax routine.

```
function getSuccess(data) {
    data = {};
    data.action = 'get-writer-data';
    data.userid = sessionStorage.getItem("user-id");
    console.log("user-id-manage-uloads=" + sessionStorage.getItem("user-id"))
    ajax('post', 'php/manage-uploads.php', data, getSuccess, "Error retrieving writer's data: ");
    $(".tr-clone");
    function getSuccess(data) {
        console.log("data=" + data);
        var trClone = $(".tr-clone");
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        var count = 0;
        for (var key in jsonData) count++
        $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
            trClone.find(".title").val(value.Title);
            trClone.find(".work-type").val(value.WorkType);
            trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
            trClone.find(".genre").val(value.Genre);
            console.log("value.FormType=" + value.FormType + ", form-type.val()=" +  trClone.find(".form-type").val());
            console.log("value.Genre=" + value.Genre + ", genre.val()=" +  trClone.find(".genre").val());
            trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
            trClone.find(".nbr-pages").val(value.NumberOfPages);
            trClone.find(".synopsis a[href='" + value.Filename + "']");
            if (key === count - 1) return false;
            trClone = trClone.clone().insertAfter($(".tr-clone:last"));
        });
    }

})
```

**console.log**

> data=[{"Title":"Mozart, Wunderkind","0":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind","WorkType":"1","1":"1","FormType":"4","2":"4","Genre":"12","3":"12","NumberOfPages":"250","4":"250","Filename":"6532744220.pdf","5":"6532744220.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"},{"Title":"Mozart,
>   Wunderkind Query-Letter","0":"Mozart, Wunderkind
>   Query-Letter","WorkType":"2","1":"2","FormType":"7","2":"7","Genre":"9","3":"9","NumberOfPages":"129","4":"129","Filename":"9981287843.pdf","5":"9981287843.pdf","OriginalFilename":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd","6":"MozartWunderkindQueryLetter.pd"}]
>
> value.FormType=4, form-type.val()=null 
>   value.Genre=12, genre.val()=null value.FormType=7,
>   form-type.val()=null value.Genre=9, genre.val()=null

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Manage Uploads</title>
        <style>
            table { 
                border-spacing:0;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            td, th {
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .nbr-pages {
                width:  48px;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Manage Uploads</h1>
        <table id="table-writer-uploads">
            <tr>
                <th>TItle</th><th>Type</th><th>Form</th><th>Genre</th><th>Length</th><th>PDF</th><th>Delete</th>                
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-clone">
                <td><input id="title" class="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus="true" /></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="work-type" name="work-type">
                        <option value="1">Fiction</option>
                        <option value="2">Non-Fiction</option>       
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-type" name="form-type">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="genre" name="genre">
                    </select>            
                </td>
                <td><input class="nbr-pages" name="nbrPages" required placeholder="Pages" /></td>
                <td><a href="" class="synopsis" target="_blank">Synopsis/Query Letter</a></td>
                <td><img src="img/icons/delete.png" alt="delete" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="js/manage-uploads.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, can you add the html snippet?

Comment: Does it happen when you reload the page? or when you load for the first time?

Comment: @Eric N: I added the HTML. It doesn't matter how many times it is reloaded - fails every time. I also tried using straight JavaScript getElementmentById, but that does not work either

Comment: I failed to mention that the select options are being added dynamically.

Comment: Unrelated to your original question you may want to check out the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option of your json_ecode() - http://php.net/json_encode - in case you want to get rid of those numeric indexes…

Comment: Can't run your test-site because the ajax in question returns "General error: A user-id must be supplied." instead of JSON…

Comment: I forgot about that. You would have to create an account first.

Comment: @ Mojtaba - after some mods (use both jQuery and JS - getElementByID) now when the form first loads it is incorrect, but correct after the next load, the incorrect again. It seems to alternate.  What led you to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that these `<select>` elements have no `<option>` elements in them. Setting the value of a `<select>` actually means to select the `<option>` with that value. But since there is no option with the value you're setting, it doesn't have any effect, so the value of the element stays at `null`.

When you add options to those dropdowns your code should work, as long as the option values match the values in the JSON. Notice that it **does** work for `.work-type`, because it has options.

Answer (score 1):

> Although assigning values to select elements seems trivial, I fail to understand why the code below sets the values to null rather than the correct ones for "form-type" and "genre". All other fields are set correctly.

You're dealing with empty `<select>` elements for "form-type" and "genre". These elements have no `<option>` elements that could be selected, therefore their value remains the empty string (not `null`).

You could try adding the option if it doesn't exist yet:

```
function selectOrCreate(list, value) {
  list.value = value;
  if (list.value === value) {
    return;
  }

  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = value;
  option.value = value;
  list.appendChild(option);
  list.value = value;
}

var newValue = 'something';
var list = document.querySelector('select.form-type');
selectOrCreate(list, newValue);
```

Comment: Please see my last comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The each method loops over an array. It doesn't passes key and values to the callback function but passes index to of the object to the function.
Hence you should get the object in first line of your function by parsing the array index. and then assign the values.

```
function getSuccess(data) {
    console.log("data=" + data);
    var trClone = $(".tr-clone");
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
    var count = 0;
    for (var key in jsonData) count++
    $.each(jsonData, function (index) {

        value = jsonData[index];

        trClone.find(".title").val(value.Title);
        trClone.find(".work-type").val(value.WorkType);
        trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
        trClone.find(".genre").val(value.Genre);
        console.log("value.FormType=" + value.FormType + ", form-type.val()=" +  trClone.find(".form-type").val());
        console.log("value.Genre=" + value.Genre + ", genre.val()=" +  trClone.find(".genre").val());
        trClone.find(".form-type").val(value.FormType);
        trClone.find(".nbr-pages").val(value.NumberOfPages);
        trClone.find(".synopsis a[href='" + value.Filename + "']");
        if (index === count - 1) return false;
        trClone = trClone.clone().insertAfter($(".tr-clone:last"));
    });
```

Comment: The documentation says it passes the key or index and the value. Why do you think it doesn't pass the value?

Comment: It does pass the value.